# How to do search filter criteria in a suitelet?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

here is my suitelet. I am also getting the condition error.
without giving the dates, it directly goes into the condition, and it is giving me an error called ""SSS_INVALID_SRCH_FILTER". yes I know this error why it is coming. this error because it has no value why it is happening means As soon as the suitelet loading itself, it is directly going into the condition. how should it be?

```
/**
*@NApiVersion 2.x
*@NScriptType Suitelet
*/
define(['N/record','N/ui/serverWidget','N/redirect','N/runtime','N/search','N/url'],function(record,serverWidget,redirect,runtime,search,url){
    function onRequest(context){
    var Request = context.request;
    var Response = context.response;
    var name = context.fieldId;
    if(Request.method == 'GET') {
        var form=serverWidget.createForm({title:"Customer entry Suitelet"});
        var primaryinfo=form.addFieldGroup({
            label:'Primary Information',
            id:'custpage_advs_primary_info',
        });
        var firstname=form.addField({
            label:'First Name',
            id:'custpage_advs_first_name',
            type:serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
            container:'custpage_advs_primary_info'
        });
        firstname.isMandatory=true;  
        var lastname=form.addField({
            label:'Last Name',
            id:'custpage_advs_last_name',
            type:serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT,
            container:'custpage_advs_primary_info'   
        });
        lastname.isMandatory=true;
 var startdate=form.addField({
            label:'Start Date',
            id:'custpage_advs_start_date',
            type:serverWidget.FieldType.DATE,
            container:'custpage_advs_primary_info'
        });
        var enddate=form.addField({
            label:'End Date',
            id:'custpage_advs_end_date',
            type:serverWidget.FieldType.DATE,
            container:'custpage_advs_primary_info'
        });
  var submit=form.addSubmitButton({
            id : 'custpage_advs_submit_record',
            label : 'Submit'
        });
        Response.writePage(form);
        form.clientScriptFileId = 91375;
        var fnameValue = Request.parameters.custparam_first_name;
        var lnameValue = Request.parameters.custparam_last_name;
 if(fnameValue){
 var fnamecustomerSearch = search.create({     //style="text-align:right"
            type:'customrecord_advs_customer_entry_form',
            filters:['custrecord_advs_first_name',"startswith",fnameValue],
        columns:[
        search.createColumn({name: "name"}),
        search.createColumn({name: "custrecord_advs_first_name"}),
        search.createColumn({name: "custrecord_advs_last_name"}),
        search.createColumn({name: "id"}),
        search.createColumn({name:"created"})
        ]
        });  
  var counter = 0;
        fnamecustomerSearch.run().each(function(result) {
            var InternalidVal = result.getValue('internalid');
            var firstname=result.getValue('custrecord_advs_first_name');
            var lastname=result.getValue('custrecord_advs_last_name');
            var recordid=result.id;
            const view_url = url.resolveRecord({
                recordType:'customrecord_advs_customer_entry_form',
                recordId: recordid,
                isEditMode: false
            });
          mysublist.setSublistValue({
            id: 'custpage_advs_sublist_internalid',
            line: counter,
            value: InternalidVal
            }); 
        mysublist.setSublistValue({
                id: 'custpage_advs_sublist_fname',
                line: counter,
                value: firstname
            });
        mysublist.setSublistValue({
                id: 'custpage_advs_sublist_lname',
                line: counter,
                value: lastname
            });
        mysublist.setSublistValue({
                line: counter,
                id: 'custpage_advs_sublist_view',
                value:"<html lang='en'><head>  <style> a {color:#ff0000; background-color: transparent; text-decoration: none;}</style></head><body><a href='"+view_url+"' target='blank'> View</a></body></html>"
            });
        counter++;
        return true;
        });
    }

    else if((startdate)&&(enddate)){
             var datecustomerSearch = search.create({
                type:'customrecord_advs_customer_entry_form',
                filters:[ 
                    ["created","onorafter","09/12/2022"],
                    'and',
                    ["created",'before',"17/12/2022"],
                    'and',
                    ['mainline',"is",true]
                ],
                 columns:[
            search.createColumn({name: "custrecord_advs_first_name"}),
            search.createColumn({name: "custrecord_advs_last_name"}),
            search.createColumn({name: "id"}),
            search.createColumn({name:"created"})
              ]
            });  
            var counter = 0;
            datecustomerSearch.run().each(function(result) {
            var InternalidVal = result.getValue('internalid');
            var firstname=result.getValue('custrecord_advs_first_name');
            var lastname=result.getValue('custrecord_advs_last_name');
            var recordid=result.id;
            const view_url = url.resolveRecord({
                recordType:'customrecord_advs_customer_entry_form',
                recordId: recordid,
                isEditMode: false
            });
        mysublist.setSublistValue({
        id: 'custpage_advs_sublist_internalid',
        line: counter,
        value: InternalidVal
        });
        mysublist.setSublistValue({
            id: 'custpage_advs_sublist_fname',
            line: counter,
            value: firstname
        });
        mysublist.setSublistValue({
            id: 'custpage_advs_sublist_lname',
            line: counter,
            value: lastname
        });
           mysublist.setSublistValue({
                line: counter,
                id: 'custpage_advs_sublist_view',
                value: "<html lang='en'><body><a class='dottedlink viewitem' href='"+view_url+"' 
                        target='blank'> View</a></body></html>"
            });
            counter++;
            return true;
            });
    }
 else{  
    return true;
    }
    }
    else{             //POST part
    var Fname= Request.parameters.custpage_advs_first_name;
    var Lname=Request.parameters.custpage_advs_last_name;
    var customRecord=record.create({
        type:'customrecord_advs_customer_entry_form',
        isDynamic:true,
    });
 customRecord.setValue({
        fieldId:'custrecord_advs_first_name',
        value:Fname
    });
    customRecord.setValue({
        fieldId:'custrecord_advs_first_name',
        value:Lname
    });
var recordId=customRecord.save({
        enableSourcing: false,
        ignoreMandatoryFields: false
        });
    redirect.toSuitelet({
        scriptId: 'customscript_advs_ss_editviewcolumn',
        deploymentId: 'customdeploy_advs_ss_editviewcolumn',
    });
        }
    }
        return{
            onRequest:onRequest
        }
        });
```

Please excuse me for a silly mistake as I have not much knowledge in scripting.

Comment: I am assuming that the error is thrown on from the first search on 'customrecord_advs_customer_entry_form' and not the second one. Assuming that is true can you please log the value of fnameValue and let us know what it is? It seems that whatever value you get it is NOT false and allows it to go through the IF statement. Perhaps you need to make sure that fnameValue != 'underfined' && fnameValue != '' && fnameValue != null.
It would also help if you can show us the full error and not just the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is coming from the filters part, it is not structured properly.

Saved search should be using the following structure:

```
search.create({
    type: 'customrecord_advs_customer_entry_form',
    filters: [
        ['custrecord_advs_first_name',"startswith",fnameValue],
        // 'AND', ['another_custfield_here',"startswith",fnameValue], -- In case you wanted to add another filter
    ],
    columns: [
        search.createColumn({name: "name"}),
        search.createColumn({name: "custrecord_advs_first_name"}),
        ....
    ]
});
```